# How to validate username with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to check username validation before signup, but it is a little bit complex, I tried too many variation but I could not.

- Username min and max length is 6 and 20
- Username can contain a-z A-Z 0-9 and ç Ç
- Username can contain underscore but can not contain start and end of username
- Username can not contain more then one underscore
- Username can contain numbers but can not contain more than **3 numbers** , number order is not important

For example;

**VALID:**

```
username
username1
username23
username456
7username
89username
123username
user_name
user_name1
1user_name2
123user_name
1u2s3er
4u5s6er
```

**INVALID:**

```
_username <-- start with underscore
username_ <-- end with underscore
_username_ <-- contains underscore more than 1, start and end with underscore
user__name <-- contains underscore more than 1
user_na_me <-- contains underscore more than 1
username1000 <-- contains number more than 3
user01name23 <-- contains number more than 3
1u2s3e4r <-- contains number more than 3
```

This regex rule is good for my first three conditions but I need add limit for numbers and underscores.

```
^(?=.{6,20}$)(?![_])[a-zA-Z0-9çÇ_]+(?<![_])$
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a side-note: If these are actual username requirements, then they are silly and are somewhat arbitrary.  I hope that these are not being implemented with the idea that they improve security, because they don't.

Comment: @cale_b these are block users to type their phone numbers (etc.) as username.

Comment: You need to post an answer instead of editing your question with the solution @Topup I've rolled it back.

Comment: Instead of forcing someone to come up with a username, why not just use their email address? Usernames have inherent problems, especially when different sites enforce different rules that force users to have to devise usernames that comply with a set of arbitrary rules...

Comment: @cale_b this is dating site, we can not show users' e-mail address as public, they need choose an username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I SOLVED, THANKS.**

**THE SOLUTION;**

```
^(?!(.*[_].*){2,}$)(?!(.*[0-9].*){4,}$)(?=.{6,20}$)(?![_])[a-zA-Z0-9çÇ_]+(?<![_])$
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex does the job. `(?!^([^0-9]*[0-9]){4,}[^0-9]*$)` counts the numbers in the regex if it is more than 4 discards, `(?!^([^_]*_){2,}[^_]*$)` counts the underscore if it is more than 1 discards.

```
^(?!^([^0-9]*[0-9]){4,}[^0-9]*$)(?!^([^_]*_){2,}[^_]*$)(?=.{6,20}$)(?![_])[a-zA-Z0-9çÇ_]+(?<![_])$
```

Comment: Better would be to show a snippet that runs through the various use-cases OP has provided, and the results from the regex for each one... (eg, does this properly DISALLOW underscores at the beginning / end?)

Answer (score -1):

Your requirements cannot be satisfied by *one* regular expression, but they can be satisfied by the judicious application of *more than one,* tied together by appropriate conditional logic in a program statement.

For instance:

- First, satisfy bullet points #1 and #2.
- Now, and in no particular order, write regular expressions to check (one at a time ...) each of the remaining three bullets, all of them assuming that the first two have already been satisfied.

Wrap all of this up in a nice, tidy program function . . .

Comment: I'm not a regex expert, but I don't see why this couldn't be done in one regular expression....